# avoid duplication when joining tables without unique id using foreign keys

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I'm facing this issue where I don't really know how to handle duplicate rows when joining two tables.

I have two tables I'd like to join

Value_x table :

```
ID          Campaign      Value_x
foo         fb            1
foo         twitter       3
bar         fb            2
foobar      ads           2
foo         organic       3
```

Value_y table:

```
ID          Campaign      Value_y
foo         organic       42
foobar      organic       17
foo         ads           12
foo         twitter       23
bar         twitter       35
```

Because of the Campaign column, ID are not unique in each table and for example, left join table output looks like this:

```
ID          t1.Campaign  t2.Campaign      Value_x  Value_y
foo         fb           organic          1        42
foo         fb           ads              1        12
```

Ideally I'd like to have the following output

```
ID          t1.Campaign  t2.Campaign      Value_x  Value_y
foo         fb           null             1        null
foo         twitter      twitter          3        23
foo         organic      organic          3        42
foo         null         ads              null     12
```

How would you handle a situation like this? I read something about `foreign keys`... I'm not familiar with this concept how can it help in this context? Or is there a way to perform a join at the campaign level?

Comment: Why can't you join also using Campaign? I will resolve the issue.

Comment: Saying you left joined is not helpful, give the code you ran. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Time to learn what joins do. PS A FK says base tables are restricted in a certain way, so join output will be restricted in certain way, but you don't need to know FKs to query.

Comment: Part of a [mcve] is a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you don't give one. We only have an example so we can only guess what that is.   Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.  To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Why no bars or foobars output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ID,
  x.Campaign AS Campaign_x,
  y.Campaign AS Campaign_y,
  Value_x,
  Value_y
FROM `project.dataset.tableX` x
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.tableY` y
USING(ID, Campaign)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your questions as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableX` AS (
  SELECT 'foo' ID, 'fb' Campaign, 1 Value_x UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', 'twitter', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', 'fb', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foobar', 'ads', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', 'organic', 3 
), `project.dataset.tableY` AS (
  SELECT 'foo' ID, 'organic' Campaign, 42 Value_y UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foobar', 'organic', 17 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', 'ads', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', 'twitter', 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', 'twitter', 35 
)
SELECT ID,
  x.Campaign AS Campaign_x,
  y.Campaign AS Campaign_y,
  Value_x,
  Value_y
FROM `project.dataset.tableX` x
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.tableY` y
USING(ID, Campaign)
-- ORDER BY ID
```

with result

```
Row ID      Campaign_x  Campaign_y  Value_x Value_y  
1   bar     fb          null        2       null     
2   bar     null        twitter     null    35   
3   foo     fb          null        1       null     
4   foo     twitter     twitter     3       23   
5   foo     organic     organic     3       42   
6   foo     null        ads         null    12   
7   foobar  ads         null        2       null     
8   foobar  null        organic     null    17
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a `full outer join`, using campaign as a condition:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.campaign as t1_campaign,
       t2.campaign as t2_campaign,
       Value_x,
       Value_y
from t1
full outer join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.campaign = t2.campaign
```

Comment: This returns null rows for every unmatched (id, campaign) pair, which is not  like the output example.